# Dialog Pop Up and return activity

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, dialog

I am new in Kotlin, I have a first activity with login, and second activity with recycle view. The data of recicle view is taken from http3 method. 
Sorry for my bad english. 
How I can show a dialogPopUp when I have code 404, and return in previous one login activity?

Answer (score 1):

OkHttp callbacks are executed on a background thread if you use enqueue and showing a dialog is a UI task therefor it needs to be run on the UI thread.

In your case you can easily do this by running your dialog code using `runOnUiThread`.

```
runOnUiThread {
    dialogPopUp("Error parameters", mContext ).showDialog()
}
```

Just as you have done in your else block. 
You can also achieve this by using a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) which has been created on the UI thread.

**Update:** Taking a closer look at your code I realized you're running `fetchJson` in a background thread by using the `doAsync` function. When you use `enqueue` on a `OkHttp.Call` you're basically sending it to be executed on a background thread so no need to use `doAsync`.
If you remove the `doAsync` you don't need to use `runOnUiThread` anymore as the callback will be executed on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

This basically means that you need to use the UI thread when calling this code. The UI thread will need to be used for showing your dialog.

You can do:

```
runOnUiThread {
    dialogPopUp("Error parameters", mContext ).showDialog()
}
```